# How to execute a function when an item is moved to another connected sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Following is the markup of my page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 4 
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 5
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 4 
    </div>
    <div class="tile-view-content">
        Item 5
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The application I am developing requires me to move one item from `#sortable1` to `#sortable2` and vice versa.

Till now I'm successful in doing this much. What I wanted to do next is to call a function when a an item from `#sortable1` is moved to `#sortable2`. Is there an event which is fired internally in the Sortable widget that I can listen to and fire my function call from?

Comment: I got the answer myself. Used the receive(ui, event) event and handled the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery sortable triggers a [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event when an item is moved to another list.

From documentation

**receive( event, ui )**

> This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list has been dropped into another list. The latter is the event target.**

You can call your function in the receive event handler as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function(e, ui){
                if(ui.sender.attr('id')=='sortable1'){
                    yourFunction(); // call your function here.
                }
             }
  });
});
```